# AngularJs Promise Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been looking for a good boilerplate on AngularJs with built-in registration and login and I found one, which works pretty well for my needs:

https://github.com/softwaremill/bootzooka/tree/master/ui

However, I cannot make it work because of line 8 in UserSessionService.js (https://github.com/softwaremill/bootzooka/blob/master/ui/app/session/userSessionService.js)

```
var loggedUserPromise = $http.get('api/users').then(function (response) {...
```

I edited it in this way:
`var loggedUserPromise = $http.get('http://www.mybackend.com/login').then(function (response) {...`

My server has only two routes, **mybackend.com/login** which gets *username* and *password* and retrieves an *apikey*, and **mybackend.com/getuser** which gets the *apikey* and returns various userdata.

The problem is that 
`var loggedUserPromise = $http.get('http://www.mybackend.com/login').then(function (response) {...` always returns a 401 since the params (username and password) are not given.

What could it be the error?

Thank you all! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved setting `var loggedUserPromise = null;` at the beginning and then

```
    userSessionService.getLoggedUserPromise = function () {
    loggedUserPromise = $http.get("http://mybackend.com/user/getself", {params: {Authorization: sessionStorage.token}}).then(function (response) {
        loggedUser = response.data;
    });
    return loggedUserPromise;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You should provide the params...

```
$http.get('http://www.mybackend.com/login', {username: "username", password: "password"}).then(function (response) {
```

Comment: I tried, but the _loggedUserPromise_ init is called before the user actually performs the login